# Django join fields in queryset

Tags: django

Is it possible to join common fields in different queryset. I have day_name = Monday in two queryset. I want to combine it into one. The reason i wanted to do it because when mapping it on frontend react. I want to see only one Monday , not two mondays.

```
[
    {
        "day__day_name": "Monday",
        "subject_name__subject_name": "Maths"
    },
    {
        "day__day_name": "Monday",
        "subject_name__subject_name": "English"
    }
]
```

I want to join these both "Monday" so that i can only return it as one "Monday" instead of two or more

```
class SubjectList(models.Model):
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name



class Day(models.Model):
    day_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    subject_name = models.ManyToManyField(SubjectList, through='time_table')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.day_name



class time_table(models.Model):
    class_number = models.ForeignKey(
        AddClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_name = models.ForeignKey(SubjectList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    begin = models.TimeField(null=True)
    end = models.TimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.class_number)
```

#Views

```
class New_time_table(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        cls = AddClass.objects.get(id=id)
        tt = (
            time_table.objects.select_related("day")
            .filter(class_number=cls.id)
            .values("day__day_name", "subject_name__subject_name")
            .distinct()
        )

        return Response(tt)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Django query can help you.

```
Model.objects.select_related('day').values('day__day_name','subject_name__subject_name').order_by('day__day_name').distinct()
```

Comment: First I'm filtering it by class_number, so it look  like this
Model.objects.filter(class_number=cls.id).select_related('day').values('day__day_name','subject_name__subject_name').distinct()

but it still returns the same

Comment: Model.objects.select_related('day').filter(class_number=cls.id).values('day__day_name','subject_name__subject_name').distinct() 

Use select_related first then filter in qs. Try above query.

Comment: still am getting duplicate mondays. Maybe because its the foreignkey. I have ipdayed my post with models and views. please check it

Comment: I forgot to add order_by clause

Model.objects.select_related('day').filter(class_number=cls.id).values('day__day_name','subject_name__subject_name').order_by('day__day_name').distinct()

Comment: tried and it prevents duplicate day name but also removing the multiple subject names too

Comment: It depend on the approach you are using while designing the database structure. You have created  both field as foreign_key.

You can create custom output as required.